# ionic calling phonegap website

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

so, i have a app developed by Ionic, I found it loads fairly fast when testing in the US. But I have users from China reported it loads very slow and stuck on splash page. At first, I thought it is server issue, after I switched to Chinese server, it behaves the same. Then I realized it is because of deviceready fired slow in China, then I suspecting when Ionic/Phonegap runs, it will connect to phonegap website, which could be slow in China.

I do have cordova.js in my index.html

```
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

After I run ionic build ios, it has cordova.js under platforms/ios, but it doest not have cordova.js under root folder

So, I want to understand how deviceready works, does it connect to phonegap website? if so, how can I disable it? where should I put the cordova.js.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't explicitly specify an internet address, cordova takes everything locally.

Comment: i don't have internet address for cordova, i do have google map api on index.html, is that everything loaded from index.html will be considered including in the deviceready process ?

Comment: No, `deviceready` is fired when "Cordova's device APIs have loaded and are ready to access".

Comment: if you have google maps script on your index.html, I think it's blocked on china

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&language=zh-CN"></script>` i have this line in my index.html, is that possible when app starts, it tries to connect to google map api, since it is blocked in China, it tries until timeout, probably around 30 seconds, so the app will stuck on splash page for 30 seconds ?

Comment: i solved, it is exactly because of the google map, it is blocked in China, so it will try to load until timeout, it is exactly 30 seconds